# "В блаженной праздности", "Блаженны праздностью", "Блаженны в праздности"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно построить фразу? Правильно ли словосочетание?
Как правильно? Это правильно?

1.В блаженной праздности своей
2.Блаженны праздностью своей
3.Блаженны в праздности своей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [БЛАЖЕННЫЙ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9), -ая, -ое; -жен, -женна, -женно. 1. Благополучный, благоденствующий, счастливый

Первый и третий варианты верны, второй кажется мне устаревшим (так же как и "счастлив праздностью своей"). Но учитывая "высокий штиль" самого слова БЛАЖЕННЫЙ, я бы и второй вариант признал корректным. В Нацкорпусе нашлось одно подходящее вхождение:

> О чувствительность, о сладкое и колющее души свойство! тобою я блажен, тобою стражду![А. Н. Радищев. О человеке, о его смертности и бессмертии (1792-1796)]

Примечание. Второй и третий варинаты практически совпадают по смылу, а первый не только отличается, но и не выражает законченную мысль.